# Relocating Double OS to New Disk

Tags: linux, windows, backup, debian, filesystems

I have a 256GB SSD which is my OS disk. I have 2 OSes in it, Debian and Windows. I want to move to a larger SSD Disk, probably 1TB (again SSD) or 512 GB (SSD).

I just have a really nice working two OSes and I have already installed and configured thousands of things in my OSes. So I don't want to lose my OS settings, apps, browser histories, everything... I want everything to stay as it is, just to move into larger disk.
Now Debian uses 128GB (ext4 filesystem) and Windows uses 128GB (NTFS filesystem), bootloader is GRUB and configured by Debian.

Any ideas to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use dd to clone the entire disk onto the new disk.

**MAKE A BACKUP BEFORE YOU DO THIS**
You'll need to have both disks plugged in and then boot from a liveCD - gparted preferably.
Then using this command, you can perform a whole disk duplicate
Where sda is your old disk, and sdb is your new disk
`dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

After the duplication is done, you will need to grow the partitions to fill the empty space.

Comment: First partition and second will be connected to each other and only one partition will be extendable.

Comment: with GParted, you can move and resize partitions. Which means that you should be able to move the second partition down the disk a bit to allow the first partition to be grown.

Comment: Are you sure about it? Because I'm going to buy NEW SSD ONLY if I become 100% sure about it. Otherwise I'll wait until I get some problem with any OS which will cause new installation, otherwise I'll keep using current setup

Comment: Yes. Partitions are movable.

Comment: So I'm just going to order SSD, if it didn't work, I'm going to ship both SSDs to your address. ;) Kidding... Thanks for your idea, will give it a try and let you know about results.

Comment: Hey! I did it, now I'm writing from 1 TB SSD disk cloned, resized and moved from my 256GB SSD. I did it all with GParted and just executed grub-install /dev/sdb, that's all! GParted took care of all, including moving and resizing. Thank you again

Comment: Awesome. Good to hear ! Please accept the answer so that everyone knows that this question has been answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Debian should be all file based... make a partition on the new disk and copy everything over.  You might have to run a command to install your boot loader (grub2-install?) but you should be able to do that while running from your old disk (specify install to your new disk)

Windows is mysterious even to Microsoft, so don't ask me about that.

Comment: I know about Debian part, I'm Linux user also. Honestly my main problem is with Windows. But thanks anyway. I hope someday Microsoft will solve that mystery about Windows ;)

Comment: For Windows I'd go with the other solution that says copy the partition.  Windows seems to like to be the first partition on the disk, so create a same sized partition and 'dd' to copy it... then expand the partition, then add a second partition for Debian.